# Access iOS device from Cocoa app on macOS

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

Does anyone know if there is a class or API that can be used to allow my Cocoa app to copy mp3 files to iOS Music libraries?  I'm looking for something similar to what CopyTrans Manager does from a PC - and what Catalina's Finder does with sync'ing iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

No public Apple sync API, AFAIK.

You might be able to use a Share Extension to AirDrop music files from a Mac to an iOS device, and let AirDrop do the copy for you.

Another possibility is a client server pair of transfer apps using the open source [PeerTalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk) libraries, and have the iOS app mediate writing to the Music Library.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I need to do this programmatically, in order to keep things simple for my users. Airdrop is another step, and in the end, iOS doesn't seem to do the right thing with the mp3 files.